Open particular view when user tap on notification in SwiftUI
i am working on SwiftUI app and i am facing one issue regarding notification. i am trying to navigate to particular screen when user tap on notification. right now what i am doing is whenever i get notification and user tap on notification my viewModifier .onNotification gets called and inside it i saved notification data using my ChatNotificationHandler class so that i can utilise this data later when i open the chattingView for showing detail and fetching new data.
I also have view Dashboard from where i listens for notification tap so that i can navigate to chatting view using .navigationDestination modifier.
i have this hierarchy for view
DashboardScreen -> InboxView -> ChattingView
When i am on DashboardScreen and if i get notification and tap on it then it should open ChattingView which is working fine, then if i click on back button it should pop to DashboardScreen again which also working fine. but the issue occurred when i am on InboxView and move to ChattingView on receiving notification then if i click on back button it is popping back to DashboardScreen instead of InboxView. So i don't know why it is behaving like this. but i think it is behaving like this because i am listening and pushing from DashboardScreen and that's why it is popping back to DashboardScreen instead of InboxView. So can you please help me out fixing this issue and tell me from where should i push to ChattingView so that it should always pop to correct view.
This is my contentView
    struct ContentView: View {
            @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
            @StateObject var deepLinkViewModel: DeepLinkViewModel = DeepLinkViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if appState.isLoggedIn || OnBoardingAuthentication.isUserLoggedIn() {
                DashboardScreen()
                    .onNotification { notificationResponse in
                        let userInfo = notificationResponse.notification.request.content.userInfo
                        let (type, data) = NotificationHandler.shared.getNotificationTypeAndData(response: userInfo)
                        if type == NotificationType.chat {
                            guard let chatData = data else { return }
                            ChatNotificationHandler.shared.saveChatDataAfternotification(jsonBody: chatData)
                            appState.moveToChattingView = true
                            ChatConfigurationManager.shared.configure()
                        }else if type == NotificationType.call { }
                    }
            } else {
                LoginView(viewModel: LoginViewModel(nil))
           }

This is my DashboardScreen listeners and modifer
          .navigationDestination(isPresented: self.$isNavigateToChattingView, destination: {
              if self.isNavigateToChattingView {
                  ChattingView(selectedRemoteUser: chatAppState.notificationChatData, organizationId: chatAppState.notificationOrganisationId ?? "", isFromTransferring: false)
              }
          })
          
          .onReceive(self.appState.$moveToChattingView) { moveToChatView in
              if moveToChatView {
                  ChatConfigurationManager.shared.configure()
                  self.isNavigateToChattingView = true
              }
          }


and lastly i am popping from ChattingView like this
    NavigationBarView(receiverDetail: viewModel.receiverDetail, userStatus: viewModel.receiverStatus, isUserTyping : viewModel.isRemoteUserTyping, onTapBackCallback: 
      {
                viewModel.messagesDataArr.removeAll()
                self.dismiss()
            })



To have any hope of making this work first you'll need to remove the view model object since that's the job of the View struct hierarchy. You'll also need to remove the non-standard use of onReceive which you won't need if you use the View structs correctly.

@malhal If i remove onReceive then how can i listen to notification tap ? how do i know when i should open ChattingView and where should i put some kind of onReceive listener when user tap on notification ?

SwiftUI isn't event driven you need to think about it differently. You need a @State for the current chat, and in onNotification you need to set the current chat. Then you just need to declare the View structs that display the chat info.

Also state needs to be decentralised across the View hierarchy using @State in each place it is needed, it shouldn't all be in one environment key and definitely not in an object.

can you provide me some example code to achieve my scenario.

I think it would be too complicated, best you get familiar with the use of View structs for modeling view data first, this post of mine might help with that: https://www.malcolmhall.com/2023/03/23/learn-swiftuis-view-struct-value-semantics-diffing-and-dependency-tracking/
